# How to use Laravel backpack for non admin user

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

In my system, there are tow types of users.

1. Admin.
2. Regular.
   For admin I am using Laravel backpack. But, I also want the backpack's features for non  admin panel also.
   What's the way?

Answer (score 2):

Usually people use Roles/Permissions to handle that.

There is a Backpack addon that will give you a kick start with cruds for user/permission/role using the Spatie Laravel Permission under the hood: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager

Then you can show some bits of your app to some users, hide some fields/columns from others etc.

Just remember that users will be authenticating using backpack guard, so you should use `backpack_user()->hasRole()`, or see the advanced configuration of the package in ReadMe.

Cheers